# Save token securely?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, oauth

To save the token in localstorage to avoid logging in every time when launching the app, I found the following link. However, is it secure?

[Ionic - How to store session token as globally (for app) accessible variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088399/ionic-how-to-store-session-token-as-globally-for-app-accessible-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Storing the token simply in local storage may be a secuirty threat you may use [Crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) to encrypt data and then decrypt using a secrate key when you need it Something like:-

```
var secretKey = 'your-secret-key';

  var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(yourtoken, secretKey).toString();
```

store this encryptedData

and when you need it back

```
 var encryptedValue = valuefrom your local;

  var decryptedData= CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedValue, secretKey)
```

[This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35740015/5621827)

Comment: How will you secure your 'your-secret-key' ?

Answer (score 0):

No, localStorage alone is not secure enough for the storage of access and/or session keys. You should encrypt the data (and not store the encryption key in your app code).

You can use the Cordova SecureStorage plugin to do this:

https://github.com/Crypho/cordova-plugin-secure-storage

It works pretty much the same as localStorage and lets you simply set and get key/value pairs.

Since the Android implementation of this secure storage uses the KeyStore, the users must have a secure screen-lock set (like fingerprint, pattern or PIN). The plugin provides functions to check this, so you will be able to give a warning (or block login) if this is not the case. Without a locked screen there is no way to save your keys in a secure way on Android.